# pip won't install package

Tags: python, pip, package

I am trying to install this package: https://github.com/gka/pyshpgeocode using pip.

I get the error message:

```
Cannot unpack file c:\users\alexis\appdata\local\temp\pip-xljjwr-unpack\pyshpgeocode.git (downloaded from c:\users\alexis\appdata\local\temp\pip-jtyh7r-build, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
Cannot determine archive format of c:\users\alexis\appdata\local\temp\pip-jtyh7r-build
```

What is this problem and how else can I install this package?

Comment: You haven't said what you did to get that error message. *Exactly* what command did you run?

Comment: pip install https://github.com/gka/pyshpgeocode.git

Answer (score 7):

**Try:**

```
pip install git+git://github.com/gka/pyshpgeocode.git
```

Comment: should be "git+https://github.com/..." to use https as transport (ssh will most probably fail).

Comment: this also seems to install without problem, but import shapegeocode does not work

Answer (score 4):

**Try:**

```
git clone https://github.com/gka/pyshpgeocode.git
cd pyshpgeocode/
python setup.py install
```

Comment: this seems to work (no error message), but then I don't seem to be able to import the package in python (import shapegeocode gets me "no module named shapegeocode")

Comment: Close your terminal and open it again :)

Comment: Check your ENV PATHS and the path where it was installed. Then check if the latter is included in the first one.

Comment: I cloned and installed in the same folder where all my other packages are. Actually this folder was not in my Path system environment variable, but I don't have any trouble importing other packages. Anyway I added the folder to Path, and still no luck (I also relaunched the console)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same install and got the same error `no module named shapegeocode`. I think that the install is not working as expected. Namely, `shapegeocode.py` is not put anywhere. So I downloaded from GitHub and put shapegeocode.py manually in `.\Lib\site-packages\pyshpgeocode-0.1-py2.7.egg` after the install (*which does update .\Lib\site-packages\easy-install.pth*).
Then it worked.