# import pyshpgeocode ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, geolocation, pyshp

I'm struggling to run pyshpgeocode.
This Python package is for reverse geocoding of data points to shapefile regions. My final goal is to be able to fetch NUTS-2 code from latitude and longitude contained in a dataframe

```
lat     | lon
54.3077 | 12.7  
51.898  | 9.26
```

PS: If you have another alternative to generate this output I am also interested by.

```
lat     | lon  | NUTS_ID
54.3077 | 12.7 | DE80
51.898  | 9.26 | DEA4
```

I managed to install it (see screenshot) in jupyter notebook but when I import the package I have an error?

[image]

When I'm looking on Anaconda the package is also install?

[image]

I don't understand the error. Do you know how to fix this issue?

Thanks you very much for your help

Comment: Can you try `import shapegeocode` (example from [here](https://github.com/vis4/pyshpgeocode) )?

Comment: yes it is not working either

Comment: Tried `%pip pip install git+https://github.com/gka/pyshpgeocode.git`? Tried suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33805339/8508004), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71799915/8508004). Despite what you say it shows, your first screenshot doesn't show it installed. You get different messages when it finishes than that. It should say something about restarting the kernel when it completes.

Comment: The command above didn't worked. I tried the following one from the post ````pip install git+git://github.com/gka/pyshpgeocode.git````  I had the following error message ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q git://github.com/gka/pyshpgeocode.git 'C:\Users\win\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-vq1oxwuf' Check the logs for full command output.